# Where/How should I define my SPI driver pins if I pretend to load the driver manually as a module

Tags: linux, driver, linux-device-driver, spi, device-tree

I am writing here because I am having some problems understanding some key concepts regarding kernel/drivers development.
First, I am going to try to describe what I want to achieve:
Develop a driver that uses the SPI to communicate receiving the payload from user space (I cannot use spidev because I pretend to transparently add some info to the payload before sending it). I want to load the module manually (insmod).

The problem I am seeing: I do not know where or how to specify my interface. If I define the interface within the device tree, is it mandatory to include the compatible field? I ask this because the driver will not be included within the kernel modules as it starts up... Maybe there is not a problem with it. In the examples, I found about spi they only speak about the BUS, Chip Select... but they do not mention MISO and MOSI, so I guess these must be defined by the device tree or maybe since you specify the bus the definition of the rest of the pins is straight forward... I would like to understand this.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Fulgo.

Comment: You seem confused, and seem to be conflating the SPI master controller with a SPI slave.  You need to study **Documentation/spi/spi-summary.rst** in the kernel source.  Presumably you have a mystery SPI slave device, and need to write a SPI protocol driver.  You don't specify pins for the SPI slave device (besides its select line when using gpio); well, maybe an attention interrupt.

Comment: First, thank you for the responde. I have taken as model something like this: https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/linux-kernel-spi-device-driver-tutorial/. I pretend to be the master and add an slave. Maybe I did not explain it well enough. My doubt is that I am not sure how the pins related to the interface are identified, that is why I mentioned the device tree.

Comment: *"SPI device driver"* is sloppy terminology; a careful read of that article indicates that they really mean a SPI *protocol* driver.  Is there an actual system/board, and a **/proc/** filesystem to review, e.g. in **/proc/iomem** is there a driver for the SPI master listed?

Comment: Ok. So, I am trying to code a protocol driver then. I have build the Linux image using YOCTO. The board uses a NXP i.MX8X and has SPI support (it has a driver to use SPI in user space https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=MX8_SPI&release=RELEASE_DUNFELL_V1.3_VAR-SOM-MX8X ) but again I do not know if I have to just enable the SPI support in the Kernel, use the device tree, both, non of them and just follow the example… I would follow the example provided by Variscite but the compatible suggest the use of spidev and I pretend to use my protocol driver.

Comment: I guess this is not an easy subject, as there is not much info about it.